# Conditionally Display Element in Angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I have a `<select>` element in my Angular component that, based on the selected item, returns the identifier of that item.

I want to know how I would be able to conditionally display a `<div>` when the identifier is either **not** `undefinded` or `0`.

I have the following code

```
<div *ngIf="this.id != undefined || this.id != null"></div>
```

However, it still display's the element even though the condition *should* theoretically be satisfied as, at the point of the `<select>` not having a value, should be `undefined`.

Are there any suggestions that would conditionally display an element using the `*ngIf` directive based on an `id` returned from a `<select>`?

Comment: Please clear your question further.

Comment: Sorry, @MuhammadBilal, I added to ask if there is any way that I can conditionally display an element using the `ngIf` directive?

Comment: There is a contradiction in your question: you tell that "I want to know how I would be able to conditionally display a <div> when the identifier is either `undefined` or `0`." but you try to do the opposite in your code. Do you want to  hide or show when it is undefined? What about the `0`? Did you mean the number or `null` or both?

Comment: Look at my fiddle in my post.

Comment: Any errors in console? Please post the code for `select` as well.

Comment: @C.Champagne I did contradict myself, thank you, I edited my question to say that I want to display the element if it is NOT undefined/null/0

Comment: @Manish no errors no, when I `console.log(this.id)` it does indeed display the value of `id` as either `undefined` when I haven't selected an item or the value thereof if I had selected an item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the `select` is set up. For eg., if it's of the following form

```html
<select #sel (change)="change(sel.value)" [(ngModel)]="id">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined">Undefined</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option">{{ option }}</option>
</select>
```

with `options = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];`

And if `id` is declared as `id: any;` in the controller, then explicit checks to `undefined` and `null` isn't required. You could do null check just with the following

```html
<div *ngIf="id && id !== 0; else undefinedBlock">
  ID is defined: {{ id }}
</div>
<ng-template #undefinedBlock>
  ID is undefined
</ng-template>
```

Comment: My `<select>` is set up as ```<select #sel (change)="change(sel.key)" [(ngModel)]="id">``` with a default ```<option>``` with ```[ngValue]``` of ```undefined``` so it should theoretically work then if I do a null check

Comment: @DylanSmyth: I've edited the answer. But what is `sel.key`? Am I missing something here? I don't think there is a `key` property in the `HTMLSelectElement`. I've replaced it with `sel.value`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how I would be able to conditionally display a `<div>`
> when the identifier is either undefinded or 0.

First of all make sure `this` is not `undefined` in all cases. then you can use sth like this :

```
<div *ngIf="this.id"></div>
```

Look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4pdn986/5/) which you can manually set `id` to `null` or remove it (e.g `undefined`)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-template` when you want to show something depending on some condition. See example

Instead of:

```
<div *ngIf="isDisplayed">Item 1</div>
<div *ngIf="!isDisplayed">Item 2</div>
```

You can do this:

```
<div *ngIf="isDisplayed; else showItem2">Item 1</div>

<ng-template #showItem2>
Item 2
</ng-template>
```